# Mapping syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out why I am getting an error to the following code. Please help.

```
def add_two(map_this_array)
  map_this_array.map { |num| "#{num} + 2 = "  num + 2 }
end
```

Specs:

```
describe "add_two" do
  it "adds 2 to each element in an array" do
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    r = ["1 + 2 = 3", "2 + 2 = 4", "3 + 2 = 5"]
    expect( add_two(a) ).to eq(r)
  end
  it "adds 2 to each element in a longer array" do
    a = [5, 7, 3, 12, 15]
    r = ["5 + 2 = 7", 
         "7 + 2 = 9", 
         "3 + 2 = 5", 
         "12 + 2 = 14", 
         "15 + 2 = 17"]
    expect( add_two(a) ).to eq(r)
  end
end
```

I am getting this error:

exercise_spec.rb:2:in `require': exercise.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
  map_this_array.map { |num| "#{num} + 2 = "  num + 2 }
                                                 ^
    from exercise_spec.rb:2:in`'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def add_two(map_this_array)
  map_this_array.map { |num| "#{num} + 2 = "  << (num + 2).to_s }
end
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks so much. Forgive my beginner-ness.

Comment: It's always the small things.

Comment: Also, in the same spirit `{ |num| "#{num} + 2 = #{num + 2}"}`